# Add a text in a string PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a text.

```
$text='userpics/115/X3WGOC0009JA.jpg';
```

I want to add a letter `p` before `X3WGOC0009JA.jpg`, so my output will be

```
 $text='userpics/115/pX3WGOC0009JA.jpg';
                  ---^
```

I am new to php, so I don't really know what to try, I was hoping you could guide me in the right direction

Comment: Since you don't have any specifications about what the string is, and which parts are fixed, the answer could as well be: `$text=str_replace('userpics/115/X3WGOC0009JA.jpg', 'userpics/115/pX3WGOC0009JA.jpg', $text);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explode by the slash by one way.

```
$exploded_text = explode('/', $text);
$new_text = $exploded_text[0] . $exploded_text[1] . 'p' . $exploded_text[2];
```

It's not the best way, but it will work.

Comment: This is not the way to go! I'm not going to downvote because it's a working method, and a simple example with `explode()`, but never use array functions where simple string functions suffice

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about **substr**, but the op looks like he wants to dynamically do this, and we would never know how long the string is, so I did it like this. @Martijn

Comment: that's why you can use strRpos (see my aswer for demo and link to docs) :)

Comment: This is marked solution, when it says in the comments **This is not the way to go**. Reading is an art. For new people: **THIS IS NOT THE WAY TO GO**. But at least it gave some points to @user3758531 ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, I would get the filename using `strrpos` and `substr`:

```
$text = 'userpics/115/X3WGOC0009JA.jpg';
$prepend_filename = 'p';

$last_slash_pos = strrpos($text, '/');

if ($last_slash_pos === false) throw new Exception('No slashes found');

$path = substr($text, 0, $last_slash_pos);
$filename = substr($text, $last_slash_pos + 1); // Add one to skip slash
```

And then you can add the `p` (as specified in `$prepend_filename`) using this:

```
$new_path = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $prepend_filename . $filename;
```

Comment: OH DEAR GOD, DIE?! THERE?!

Comment: My favorite quote for using die() "
If a supermarket freezer breaks down, a customer who wanted to buy a tub of ice cream doesn't expect to be kicked out of the building."

Comment: I replaced ``die`` with an exception

Comment: Why the big messages? Why not a soft exit? Why does the page have to stop working? Just only excucute code when the slash is present , or else nothing )

Answer (score 0):

There is a function, [`substr_replace()`](https://www.php.net/substr_replace), which can **insert a string at a point you want**.
We combine this with [`strRpos()`](https://www.php.net/strrpos) which we can use to **find the first slash, LOOKING IN REVERSE**:

```
$string = substr_replace($string, 'p', strrpos($string, '/')+1 );
```

This will insert `'p'` in `$string`. At the position of the `'/'` in `$string`. The +1 corrects the 'cursor' to the character AFTER the slash.

---

**Why not use the explode functions?**
Very simple: Those are slow. String functions like `strpos()` and `substr_replace()` are VERY fast, especially on small strings.
Arrays are WAY slower in php, so don't go there unless you have to. For simple string- manipulation you should use simple string functions (sounds easy when you put it like that doesnt it?).

In a simple test I benchmarked the explode variant like user3758531's VS the string variant like mine:
100.000 tries with **arrays**: **1.5** sec
100.000 tries with **strings**: **0.9** sec

In this one situation, with this one action timing doesnt really matter. But apply this way of thinking thoughout the website and you will notice it speeding up/slowing down.

Answer (score 0):

Based on his question, I think all he wants to do is:

```
$text='userpics/115/'.'p'.'X3WGOC0009JA.jpg';
```

Comment: I doubt that, that would be very easy, in that case you could easily just add the string to the original string

Comment: @Martijn His other questions in the last 2 3 days suggest he just started learning PHP. so i thought , this might as well be what he didn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just setting you variables and concatenation if you doing this a bunch.

```
$p = 'p';

$new = "userpics/115/" . $p . "X3WGOC0009JA.jpg";
```

Comment: He says he has the whole string, I doubt he can split it there, I think the splitting is the problem to begin with